# Can't find the CSS element that disturb my layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was working on the customization of the template of my web and suddenly, the main menu for some specific pages get disturbed (the frontpage and some other pages are OK).

One of my changes disturbed the rest and I can't find the element that causes the problem.

I am searching for more than one hour already (via Firebug and the coding tool in Chrome "F12") and can't see it.

The first item in the menu had a different color and the border-bottom of the "li" elements of the submenu is bigger than it should be (has to be 1px).

I don't want to spam but I think it will be easier if I put the links:

frontpage: http://imagingshop.dreamhosters.com/ (menu = OK)
one of the problematic pages: http://imagingshop.dreamhosters.com/sharpzoom
--> you will immediately see the difference

the Contact, Services and Tutorials pages are ok, the problem is only at the Product pages.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you isolate the problem in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks you all! And for the border of the submenu I found it as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This css

```
#main-menu .menu a.active-trail
{
color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

gives the white color to your product.

Change it like

```
#main-menu .menu a.active-trail
{
color: #AAAAAA!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class `active-trail` it makes your "products" text white.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in file http://imagingshop.dreamhosters.com/sites/default/files/css/css_qLs_s8izWGQLERkNiGEldBLDTETyDfKs-iFsVg6MKfE.css:

## main-menu .menu a.active-trail {

color: #FFF !important; <--- remove this line

Answer (score 1):

```
#main-menu .menu a.active-trail {
color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove !important from color attribute

css_qLs_s8izWGQLERkNiGEldBLDTETyDfKs-iFsVg6MKfE.css

```
#main-menu .menu a.active-trail {
color: #FFF;
background: #C00;
}
```